# Extending Prestashop functionalities

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm currently trying to develop and e-commerce solution for a client.

He has some specifics needs : he wants to add some artists every week and each artist has his own collection.
I'm looking forward into prestashop but as it only covers a default e-commerce solution, it doesn't include such things as artists or collection.

Is there a way to extend prestashop functionalities in order to add an entire Artists/Collection module or is it better to do it "from scratch" with a framework?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop is developed in MVC (model, view, controler) wich makes it very scalable. Also have extensions called modules. You can check all the modules in  [Prestashop Addons](http://addons.prestashop.com/)